# Background won't show with HTML5

Tags: css, html, doctype

My background won't show if I use html5 doctype.
I have uploaded both versions, one with doctype, one without.

http://ndv.site50.net/with/Planet.html
http://ndv.site50.net/without/Planet.html

I have tried everything, renaming all files, etc, but I can't manage to fix it.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add this css property to body:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Once you build a page bigger than the browser's window, if you don't use this property the background will stretch to the size of the body content, instead of stretching to just the size of the window.

Comment: true... because once he builds a page bigger than the browser's window if he doesn't use this property the background will stretch to the size of the body content instead of stretching to just the size of the window

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css file.

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
```